# regression model for skewed distribution in python

Tags: python, regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sTrN.png)

I would like to make a linear regression model.
Predictor variable: 'Sud grenoblois / Vif PM10' has a decaying exponent distribution. you could see on the graph. As fas as I know, regression supposes
normal distribution of the predictor. Should I use a transform of variables or another type of regression?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply logarithm transformation to reduce right skewness.

If the tail is to the left of data, then the common transformations include square, cube root and logarithmic.

I don't think you need to change your regression model.